# Referencing elements from two-dimensional array with a single value

Tags: c++

I am probably missing something fundamental, but i cannot find a solution to the following issue.
I have a two-dimensional array of some float elements and i am trying to find a way to be able to reference them by using only a single value.
Example:

```
float test[5][50];
test[3][25] = 34.67;
cout << test[3][25] << endl;
int id = 25;
cout << *test[id*5+3] << endl;
```

I am hoping to get same result from both cout. Instead my output looks like this:

```
34.67
Segmentation fault
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks very strange and counter-intuitive. Why are you attempting this?

Comment: It's been awhile, and I've only done code like this reading bitmap type data so this might not apply but... I'd be wary of assuming your memory is layed out in a linear set without any end of line buffer bytes or anything that would throw your math out if you don't compensate. When reading bitmap data for instance you have to know the Stride as well as the dimensions to access the data with single dimension indexer.  If this is not relevant feel free to ignore :)

Comment: I can't think of any good reasons to do this. Maybe if you provide more context about your goal, someone can come up with a better solution.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, doing array math is not the way to go. If you want to access it as a single dimensional array, then define it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without testing, I think something like this might work. Note that C++ arrays are major->minor from left dimension to right dimension.

```
float test[5][50];
test[3][25] = 34.67;
cout << test[3][25] << endl;
int id = 25;
float* test2 = &test[0][0]
cout << test2[(3 * 50) + id] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I indexed it the wrong way. But why do I need to copy it to a pointer first? Why can't I just say `cout << test[(3*50)+id] << endl;` ?

Comment: @rbx Because even though the syntax looks exactly the same, `test[]` is an array of `float[50]` NOT a `float*` or `float[]` . When you say `test[n]` you're asking the compiler for the `n` th ROW, not the `n` th item with row wrapping. You need to tell the compiler you want to treat the 2d array as one dimensional with the intermediate. Also, why do you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The crash is because you are trying to read the contents of the element as a memory address

`*test[id*5+3]` means `int address = test[id*5+3];`  then read memory at address.
If that address is 0 or memory you don't own then it will crash.

Answer (score 2):

test is a `float[][]` with 5 elements (each of which is a `float[]` with 50 elements), and you are referring to `test[128]`. Hence the seg fault.You need to convert from single index to subscript using integer division and mod:

```
cout << test[id/50][id%50] << endl;
```

You should `assert(id/50<5);` to make sure your index is within bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a two-dimensional bitmap (image) with a single reference is often useful.

Use:

```
int image2D[dim2][dim1];
int *image1D = &image2D[0][0];
```

Now

```
image2D[i][j] == image1d[i*dim1+j]
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the first comment, that you really shouldn't do it, but I'll answer anyway.

I think that if you try:

```
cout << test[id*5+3] << endl;
```

it should work. There is no need to dereference with *.

Comment: That will actually give him the `id*5+3`th row (which doesn't exist). All bets are off on behavior although it might just degrade to `void*` and print the nonexistent row's address.

Comment: @Mark The point I was trying to make was that the segmentation fault was the dereference. I agree that the math my math isn't right but neither was his :-)